# How to display comments added via frontend in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a single blog section containing a form for submitting comments.the form code is :

```
<ul class="comment-list listnone">
    <li class="comment">
        <div class="comment-body mb40">
            <div class="comment-author"><img src="<?php echo content_url().'/themes/medilife/images/user-pic-2.jpg'?>" alt="" class="img-responsive img-circle"> </div>
            <div class="comment-info">
                <div class="comment-header"><h3 class="user-title">Name</h3></div>
                <div class="comment-content">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                    <div class="reply"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Reply</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

i have used an ajax call to append the newly added comments to existing comments, the ajax call is :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#reply-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = jQuery('#name').val();
        var email = jQuery('#email').val();
        var comment = jQuery('#textarea').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"<?=site_url()?>/ajaxcomment.php",
            data:{name:name, email:email, comment:comment},
            success:function(html){
                jQuery('.comment-list').append(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and the ajax file is :

```
<?php
    include 'wp-load.php';
    $id = array(
        'post_title'    =>  $_POST['name'],
        'post_type '        => 'comment'
    );
    // var_dump($userdata);
    $user_id = wp_insert_post( $id ) ;
    // print_r($user_id);
    $comment= $_POST['comment'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];

    add_post_meta($user_id,'comment',$comment);
    add_post_meta($user_id,'email',$email);
?>
<ul class="comment-list listnone">
    <li class="comment">
        <div class="comment-body mb40">
            <div class="comment-author"><img src="<?php echo content_url().'/themes/medilife/images/user-pic-1.jpg'?>" alt="" class="img-responsive img-circle"> </div>
            <div class="comment-info">
                <div class="comment-header"><h3 class="user-title"><?php echo $_POST['name'];?></h3></div>
                <div class="comment-content">
                    <p class="cmnt"><?php echo $_POST['comment'];?></p>
                    <div class="reply"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Reply</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

since i havent made the get method dynamic in my html after the ajax call the appended data is lost. is there anyway to get the comments from backend and make it dynamic in the htm portion.

i have created a custom post type named comments, but since the comments are added via frontend they dont appear as posts in wordpress backend

Comment: Why are you trying to store comments as posts? WordPress already natively supports comments…

Comment: i read about it and activated it.. but i could only add comments via backend and not in front end

Comment: What do you mean by "in front end" and "via backend"?

Comment: frontend means the comment form is in my site and backend means the admin panel and control centre of the wordpress